# Function that takes columns from another dataframes and returns the, in a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Im very new so please excuse this question if it's very basic but I have a data frame with some columns (Open High Low and Close). I'd like to write a simple function that just takes the Close column (as a default but allows for any of the other columns to be specified) and just returns a new data frame with just that column.

My code below just returns a dataframe with the column name but no data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Book2.csv')
df = df.loc[2:, :'Close'].drop('Unnamed: 7', axis=1)
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'X'}, inplace=True)
df.drop(['O', 'H', 'L'], axis=1, inplace=True)


def agg_data(ys):
    agg_df = pd.DataFrame(ys, columns=['Y Values'])
    return agg_df


result = agg_data(df['Close'])
print(result)
```

Comment: You can just do ````result = df[['Close']]````. The double square brackets will do it for you.

Comment: I tried hacking into your system to access Book2.csv and run your code, but I couldn't, because I'm not a hacker. Unfortunately, short of that, I have no other way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: im more curious why my syntax is producing an empty data frame.Book2.cvs is just a mess of data. the final df that results in from that code is just rows of data with the column headers (Open, High, Low, Close)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put data into pd.DataFrame() when your data already is a pandas dataframe. Correct me if I'm misunderstanding what you want, but as I see it this should be sufficient:

```
result = df['close'].copy()
```

If you don't use copy(), your initial *df* will also change if you're making changes to *result*, so since you want a new dataframe (Or a series, since it's one-dimentional) that's probably what you want.